# What is the best way to allow a user to upload a large csv file (> 5GB) from the browser to a python flask server?

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, flask

I am working on a single page web app that will allow users to upload a large CSV file (greater than 5 GB) and will then send it to a python flask server to be streamed to a database. Large CSVs are hard to read in python because of memory issues so I think it's best to send the csv data to a database like sqlite and then query the database to get the data back. However, I tried reading a csv file of 6.9 GB by chunks using `pandas` and then using the `df.to_sql()` method to store it into an sqlite db but it took about an hour which would be inefficient in a flask server and a terrible user experience. I have been doing some research and it seems that I can use worker processes/task queues like `Celery` or `Redis Queue` to speed up the process but not to sure how to go about it or if I need sockets to do this. I am a junior dev so any reference to tutorials, examples, or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unluckily we can not give this kind of broad advise on SO. This site is about giving *specific* answers to *specific* questions. There are many celery tutorial out there and if you get stuck at one point you can come here and ask about that point.

Comment: Hi, @Mario and welcome to SO! Klaus was right, it is too broad of a question. But generally speaking, you're on the right track, you just need to do more research: accept a file in flask using streaming upload to save memory, then fire off a background task (celery or cron can work as well) to ingest the file. I would also consider postgres or mysql for a database instead of sqlite in this case.